# Using float property inside table-cell element slides previous content down

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use floating divs inside the element with the `display:table-cell` property, but I have encountered unexpected behavior.

Why are the elements in the first column affected by the elements in the second column (`a` in the first column is suddenly moved down)? Is there any way to prevent that behavior?

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.cell a {
    padding: .5em;
    border: .1em solid black;
}
.cell+.cell a {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <a>cell1</a>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <a>cell2</a>
        <a>cell2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always post a complete code example in your question.

Comment: I'm tempted to give you a different solutions (using a different approach) but first, would you edit your question with a reason as to why you are using display: table-cell? This is a very specific display form. I'm guessing you are used to the old <table> layout form and trying out the <div> layout but you are having trouble crossing to the good side lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fascinating behavior.  I have several theories.  Although I agree that using `display: table-cell` seems random, there are occasional uses for it so I'll leave that in there for my answer.  I'm sorry if my answer is overtly complex; I'll try to simplify it:

**First of all**

To understand why the element is pushed down is a matter of understanding how vertical-alignment works for `table-cell`s:

The only `vertical-align` property values that should be used for `table-cell`s are `top`, `middle`, and `bottom` (see [this excellent css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)).  Anything else is undefined behavior--meaning browsers may do whatever they want with them, and different browsers will probably do different things.  This is probably not [ever...] what we want.

By default, browsers will give all `td` elements `vertical-align: middle`.  So when you're creating a normal HTML `table`, you never necessarily have to worry about the `vertical-align` property.

On the other hand, all normal elements, by default, have `vertical-align: baseline`.  This value on elements with `display: table-cell` causes our dreaded undefined behavior.

You are manually constructing a table using elements that won't, by default, behave like a table (this is why you probably shouldn't be using `display: table-cell` when you're not completely sure what you're doing).  You therefore have to put **all** the default styles of a table on by yourself.  This includes specifying a `vertical-align: top|middle|bottom` property for your `.cell`s.

**So why is it only pushed down when I float the elements in one cell?**

Again, it's undefined behavior.  When you don't float, this doesn't seem to cause a problem; the elements are still able to intelligently find the baseline of the inner text and vertically align themselves so they appear where you'd expect them.  When you float here, there are two things to note:

> 1) Remember that floating removes an element from the normal flow of the DOM.  This means other elements, **including the element's parent**, can't interact with that element like they normally would.
>
> 2) Remember that `table-cell`s are intelligent; they can dynamically, **vertically position their children**.

Combining these two leads me to think that when you float those elements:

1) Their `.cell` parent is losing track of where the text is inside them.

2) It can't properly communicate to its neighbor cell where the baseline is--it just uses its bottom edge.

3) The neighbor cell correctly vertically aligns its content to that baseline, resulting in the shift downward.

**The fix?**

Put `vertical-align: middle` responsibly on your `.cell`s:

```
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

(And the `a` tags should probably be `display: inline-block` too).  Here's an updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vg5j7xgc/10/).  Regards.

Comment: Excellent! The only note: the `a` tags should be `display: block`. In this way all 'permited' `vertical-align` modes (top, middle, bottom) works properly. Don't know why =) Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, bowheart, two spaces after sentences is a holdover from when it was required on typewriters. It has never been necessary on computers and the second space is ignored in markup rendering anyway.

Comment: @TylerH That's super intriguing that you'd bring that up.  I didn't actually know that that originated from anywhere.  So thank you.  I'll assure you that I'm perfectly aware that browsers reduce all sequences of un-escaped whitespace in HTML to a single space character.  I've never (well, since I was little) used a typewriter.  It's just a personal preference that I use in all my writing as an author/playwright.  It bugs me just a little every time I see sentences smashed together.

Comment: @bowheart Yep, typewriters used mono spacing for all characters since they were purely mechanical, so it was necessary to create two spaces between sentences so that people could tell where they ended at a glance! (PS, great answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have a plus sign (i.e.: [adjacent siblings selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)) in that rule `.cell+.cell a`, removing it works as expected:

```
.cell a {
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vg5j7xgc/5/

Comment: Should the op reaaaaaly need table-cell at all, this is a good answer. But mu gut tells me, he probably doesn't need table-cell. In my 10+ years I think I've needed this a handful of times. (y)

Comment: Can you explain why the element is pushed down?

Comment: Yes, but i need the `float:left` effect only in `cell2`. And my question is mostly about css mechanics at all, cause i cant understand why it works in such way. To LOTUSMS: i don't know the simple way to reach the needed behavior without `table-cell`

Comment: @alirezasafian If you remove the *.css+.css a* rule you will see that all 3 remain aligned, what is happening is that such rule applies the float element to the second and third cell, because both .cell share the same parent and the first .css immediately precedes the second .css

Comment: @Razial have you tried with .cell:nth-child(2) { background-color:red; } http://jsfiddle.net/vg5j7xgc/9/

Answer (score 1):

[CSS 2.1 says](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/tables.html#height-layout)

> The baseline of a cell is the baseline of the first in-flow line box
>   in the cell, or the first in-flow table-row in the cell, whichever
>   comes first. If there is no such line box or table-row, the baseline
>   is the bottom of content edge of the cell box.

This is the key to understanding the behaviour. It's very technical, so I'll try to pick it apart.

The first cell has an in-flow line box, formed by the text "cell1". Its baseline is the text's baseline.

For the second cell, all the non-whitespace text is removed from the flow by `float:left' and all the whitespace is removed by the normal whitespace rules. Therefore, it doesn't have any in-flow line boxes. Nor does it contain any in-flow table rows, so the baseline of cell is bottom of the content edge of the cell box.

Since the table-cell forms a [block formatting context](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#block-formatting), the cell's content includes the floats, so the bottom content edge is the bottom of the floats.

The first cell has a vertical-align value of `baseline` by default. Therefore, it must be aligned with the baseline of the second cell, which is the bottom of the floats.

Now, the `a` element  in the first cell is a non-replaced inline element. [Its height rules](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) say

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box
>   start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do
>   with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when
>   calculating the height of the line box.

... And the height of the first table-cell is the height of its stack of line boxes, which, in this case, is the line-height of the one and only line it contains. So the `a` elements padding and border don't affect the height of the table cell and in fact escape the first table cell, which you can see if you add a [`background-color` to the cells](http://jsfiddle.net/vg5j7xgc/15/)

The resolution, as has already been pointed out, is to [add `vertical-align:middle` to the first cell](http://jsfiddle.net/vg5j7xgc/16/).